# is this the default working of reduce method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```js
const product_list=[{id:1},{id:2}]
const temp_products=[{id:1,quantity:10},{id:2,quantity:20}]
product_list.map(prod=>{
    console.log(temp_products.reduce((init,curr_prod)=>{
       return curr_prod.id == prod.id ? curr_prod.quantity : null
    }))
})

// null
// 20
```

Condition for the second object executes to true but for the first object, it executes to false (it must be true).

reduce function fetches the Quantity from the second object correctly for the first obj it returns null.
Why is it so??

Comment: Welcome to SO! The `map` here seems problematic. If you're not returning anything from the callback, use `forEach` or skip it entirely. What are you trying to do here, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nuance of `reduce` is that, if you do not provide a seed value the first call to the function passes the first and second element.

The other issue with your code is that you need to return `init` value from `reduce`

Also, no need to use `map` just use `forEach` if youre not interested in the result of `map`

```js
const product_list=[{id:1},{id:2}]
const temp_products=[{id:1,quantity:10},{id:2,quantity:20}]
product_list.forEach(prod=>{
    console.log(temp_products.reduce((init,curr_prod)=>{
       return curr_prod.id == prod.id ? curr_prod.quantity : init
    },null))
})

// 10
// 20
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the purpose of the function `map`, probably you want to use the function `forEach` instead because it seems you want to loop.

Remember, the function `map` it's used for transforming the objects of a source array into a new structure in a new array.

Likewise, I think a possible approach should be the function `find` which finds the first match *(according to a condition)* within an array.

```js
const product_list = [{
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 2
}]
const temp_products = [{
  id: 1,
  quantity: 10
}, {
  id: 2,
  quantity: 20
}];

product_list.forEach(prod => {
  let found = temp_products.find(curr_prod => {
    return curr_prod.id == prod.id;
  });
  
  if (found) 
    console.log(found.quantity);
});
```

Comment: `.map` is for applying some function to each of the array items (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky I know that! my statement is regarding the real usage of the OP.

Comment: Oh, sorry then :)